# Facebook OAuth Callback redirected to API not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth

I'm trying to register Users through my API using Facebook OAuth.

The problem is I keep getting this error:

```
The redirect_uri URL is not supported
```

the redirect_uri is:

```
redirect_uri=localhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback
```

or, simplified:

```
localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback
```

which is the URL where it's supposed to being redirected. (API is running on localhost:3000)

The client application is running on localhost:4000

These are my configurations in developers.facebook.com:

Settings > Basic

[image]

Products > Facebook Login
[image: Products > Facebook Login]

Comment: Your callback has to be part of the “website” that you have set up to handle user login, it is not supposed to go to any kind of API directly. Redirect back to what you have running under :4000, and handle the necessary steps (exchanging code for token) there.

Comment: That's what I was hoping not to do, but it really seems the only way. Thank you!